# vexflow javascript produces no output

Tags: javascript

I am not sure what I am missing, but my vexflow test page simply does not output anything. Any help will be appreciated. This is the url to the test page http://www.gratun.org/test/vexflow.php.

I include the script /vexflow-debug.js in the head section. Then I have the javascript

```
   <script>
   VF = Vex.Flow;

   var div = document.getElementById("boo")
   var renderer = new VF.Renderer(div, VF.Renderer.Backends.SVG);


   renderer.resize(500, 500);
   var context = renderer.getContext();
   context.setFont("Arial", 10, "").setBackgroundFillStyle("#eed");

   var stave = new VF.Stave(10, 40, 400);
   stave.addClef("treble").addTimeSignature("4/4");
   stave.setContext(context).draw();
   </script>
```

And the div in the body

```
   <div id="boo"></div>
```

Then nothing appears, no output at all from the script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion on all the samples at vex-flow, the scripts are quite all over the place on different morphing and intentionally obfuscated. Here is what I did. Download all resources in /var/www/html/JAZZ folder.

```
wget http://vexflow.disqus.com/embed.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/css/bootstrap.min.css
wget http://static.vexflow.com/css/bootstrap-editable.css
wget http://static.vexflow.com/css/alertify.core.css
wget http://static.vexflow.com/css/alertify.default.css
wget http://my.vexflow.com/css/app.6d53e562a278d7dfcfee5ad978ac34d4.css
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/ace/ace.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/jquery.min.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/bootstrap.min.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/bootstrap-editable-inline.min.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/alertify.min.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/vexflow-min.81.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/tabdiv-min.81.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/underscore-min.js
wget http://static.vexflow.com/js/support/paper.min.js
wget http://my.vexflow.com/js/app.9da856e68cab5dda7469337bb6f6f2eb.js -C ./theapp.js
```

Then I created a simple page as: see it's source here

http://23.111.69.110/muzikian/